# How to scrollTo only a divs, not the whole page?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using a jQuery's scrollTo plugin and I want to scroll a divs under a "mask" horizontally, and that works for me very well, **but** I don't want to scroll a page vertically (of course smooth scrolling don't want to work with that, there's only a jump like in HTML a few pixels down (according to vertical resolution of monitor, because when whole page is displayed - nothing happens)

How can I disable vertical jump to div?

**Update**

i found an answer - onclick="return false"

thx for help guys!

Answer (score 1):

If you are not already you should check out the [scrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) jQuery plugin, which provides smooth animations and scrolling of specific elements.

However to me it sounds more like animation of divs rather than scrolling, in which case you would need to animate the absolute position of the div.

If you wish the scroll position to move instantly then use jQuery's `scrollTop(200)` in order to change the scroll position of an element.

Comment: i use scrollto plugin, and that works perfect for my divs but all i want to disable standard html jump to divs. imagine page scrollable horizontally, and for ex. Firefox window height is to little to show all page vertically

Comment: Are you saying that invoking the `scrollTo` method on one of you divs makes the page first move to view the div before scrolling it?

Comment: yes!! but page move instantly, without animation - so i want to disable it

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#the_div').scrollLeft($('#the_div').scrollLeft()+300);
```

Or, using the [scrollTo plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo):

```
$('#the_div').scrollTo('+300', {axis:'x'});
```

Comment: and that will disable vertical jump to object?